# Is there a way to convert one column in csv file to upper using shell commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, etl

Please help me with a BASH code which targets a particular column in a csv file and converts it to upper.
For instance, if file_a.csv has the following columns:

```
man,woman,boy,girl
woman,man,boy,girl
boy,girl,man,woman
girl,boy,woman,man
```

I want to convert column 2 to upper in order to have:

```
man,WOMAN,boy,girl
woman,MAN,boy,girl
boy,GIRL,man,woman
girl,BOY,woman,man
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: If your CSV is plain (no quoting) then you can use `awk`;  give it a try

Comment: ok. will work on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with sed:

```
sed 's/[^,]*/\U&/2' file_a.csv
```

- This will replace the 2nd string with with zero or more non-comma characters with it's uppercase equivalent

Comment: this works just fine

Comment: @TheTrueJACKSONIAN That is a GNU `sed` solution, so basically it will only work on Linux